# Parsing through excel using ruby gem "creek"

Tags: ruby, excel

Hey guys so I am trying to parse through an excel file through the ruby gem "creek", it parses the the rows accurately but I want to just retrieve the Columns, such as only the data in the "A" cloumn. Outputs the whole excel documents correctly.

```
require 'creek'
creek = Creek::Book.new 'Final.xlsx'
sheet= creek.sheets[0]

sheet.rows.each do |row|
  puts row # => {"A1"=>"Content 1", "B1"=>nil, C1"=>nil, "D1"=>"Content 3"}
end
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use Creek? It doesn't seem optimized for getting columns, it'll be a little messy. It's optimized for stream parsing large files.

Comment: Could recommend another parsing gem like "roo". I am having a hard time understanding how to use parsing gems for excel. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creek doesn't make it easy to extract column information because it stores the column and row smashed together in a string hash key.

The more popular [Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) allows you to do things like `sheet.column(1)` and get an entire column. Very simple.

If you absolutely must have creek, I noticed that there is an add-on to Creek called [Ditch](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ditch/0.1.0) which adds some column-fetching capability. Example:

```
  sheet.rows.each { |r|
    puts "#{r.index} #{r.get('A')} - #{r.get('B')}"
  }
```

Finally, if you want to do it with Creek and no add-ons, use Hash#select:

```
sheet.rows.each do |row|
  puts row.select{ |k,v| ["A", "B"].include? k[0]}
end
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to retrieve just the column value instead of with the column label ie . the A, B etc,  how will I tweak your last approach.

Comment: @ultrasamad To get the value using `Ditch`, use `row.lookup('key')`. In Creek, every row is a hash, so you can use `Hash#values`

Answer (score 0):

To read the individual columns you can use Creek :: Sheet # simple_rows method

For example, to read the first and third columns:

```
require 'creek'
creek = Creek::Book.new 'Final.xlsx'
sheet_first = creek.sheets.first

# read first column A
col_first = sheet_first.simple_rows.map{|col| col['A']} #=> Array containing the first column

# read third column C
col_third = sheet_first.simple_rows.map{|col| col['C']} #=> Array containing the third column
```